# The output for the lowest measurment is always 0, but I dont udnerstand why

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, input

```
public class MinMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("ERROR: Bitte mindestens eine Zahl als Argument  ̈ubergeben!");
            return;
        }

        long[] measArray = new long[args.length];
        
        long lowestMeas = measArray[0];
        long highestMeas = measArray[0];
        

        for(int i = 0; i < measArray.length; i++){
            measArray[i] = Long.parseLong(args[i]);

            if(measArray[i] < lowestMeas){
                lowestMeas = measArray[i];
            }
            if(measArray[i] > highestMeas){
                highestMeas = measArray[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lowestMeas);
        System.out.println(highestMeas);
          
    }
}
```

If I open the terminal with

java MinMax 2 3 2

i get the output
0
3

and its viceversa

java MinMax -9 -3 -10 -1
-10
0

I think im doing something wrong in the for-loop because the input seems to be right how it is processed?

Comment: `lowestMeas` and `highestMeas` are initialized as 0 so of course if the lowest value is higher than 0 you will still get 0 and if the highest is lower than 0 you'll still get 0. Put something inside the array before initializing those values.

Comment: `new long[args.length]` does not add any elements to the new array

Comment: By the way, this is the perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger (or debugging in general). Take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: thanks a lot Federico, will study this!

Answer (score 2):

At this stage

```
    long[] measArray = new long[args.length];
    long lowestMeas = measArray[0];
```

`measArray`  does not have any values apart from the default value of `0`, so unless a negative value is entered then

```
if(measArray[i] < lowestMeas){
```

will always be false

Comment: thanks a lot, i was so stupid i just had to:

 long lowestMeas = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
 long highestMeas = Long.parseLong(args[0]);

Comment: Yes or you could intialiaze `lowestMeas` to Interger.MAX_VALUE